# document.createElement / document.body.appendChild not creating / writing div where executed

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I have a div with the ID 'headercontent' and I have a script that will write a link amongst the others if javascript is enabled on the users system, but also has a backup using noscript just in case the user does not have javascript enabled.

The code runs fine and the 'a' element is written when executed but the problem is that the code is not written in the div it is executed in. It writes it outside of the 'headercontent' div and it ignores the class style completely, even though it is written in the rendered code. I'm not too worried about the styling/class because I can just add a style attribute to the element and get it written by javascript if necessary, but I'm more concerned about why its writing the code outside of this div.

My code is:

```
<div id="headercontent">
    hey, this is a div.
    <a href="#" class="button">This is a link</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">This is another link</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        writeask()
        function writeask() {
         var writeaskbox = document.createElement('a');
         writeaskbox.href = 'javascript:askbox()';
         writeaskbox.className = 'button';
         writeaskbox.innerHTML = 
             ['Ask'].join(' ')
         document.body.appendChild(writeaskbox);
        }

        function askbox(){
         var askbox = document.getElementById('askbox')
         if (askbox.style.display == 'none') {
          askbox.style.display = 'block'
          askbox.style.height = '150px'             
         } else {
          askbox.style.display = 'none'
          askbox.style.height = '0px'
         }
        }
    </script>
    <noscript><a href="/ask" class="button">Ask</a></noscript>
</div>
```

How do I get the writeask() function to create this a element in the same div it is executed in? So that the final output is:

```
<div id="headercontent">
    hey, this is a div.
    <a href="#" class="button">This is a link</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">This is another link</a>
    <a href="javascript: askbox()" class="button">Ask</a>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div id="headercontent">
    hey, this is a div.
    <a href="#" class="button">This is a link</a>
    <a href="#" class="button">This is another link</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript: askbox()" class="button">Ask</a>
```

I'm still a beginner with javascript so I'm rather puzzled now. If anyone could help, that would be well appreciated.

Thank you in advance. Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are invoking writeask() before the function exists so, in this case you should do it the other way around. It should be:

```
function writeask() {}
function askbox(){}

writeask();
```

and then you are appending it to the body

```
document.body.appendChild(writeaskbox);
```

, not the div, as it should be

```
document.getElementById("headercontent").appendChild(writeaskbox);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll accept your answer since you pointed out the  error of the order of my script. This worked perfectly.

Comment: @DanS The function - function call order is not an issue. JavaScript Hoists the function definition to the top of the given scope.

Comment: @Shad, i understand Hoisting. Tell me what would be different in this case, if he invokes the function before declaring it and i'll bow to your -1. I really think declaring the functions beforehand, improve the readability and, if Dan S is a javascript beginner, i don't believe he took Hoisting into consideration...

Comment: @Shad I don't see any difference in functionality or output when the function is called before or after the function is defined? (sorry if that's incorrect terminology) but it behaves exactly the same, however it does make more logical sense (to me at least) to call it after even if it doesn't matter. But I assume it is somewhat quicker (barely noticeable) to read/processed by a computer to be called after it knows the function exists rather than having to hunt for it later in the code (longer scripts).

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez I didn't down vote it, I voted for it as the best answer, thank you!

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez I down voted because you called it an error, and it most certainly was not one. Readability concerns do not errors make.

Comment: @DanS The JavaScript parser doesn't have to do any extra searching; at runtime it hoists _all_ such function and var declarations to the beginning, and then proceeds with the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
document.body.appendChild(writeaskbox);
```

use

```
document.getElementById("headercontent").appendChild(writeaskbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
document.body.appendChild(writeaskbox);
```

You should do the following:

```
document.getElementById('headercontent').appendChild(writeaskbox);
```